# Populate activeX comboboxes on different generated sheets (Excel 2007)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

i'm a beginner and it's been days since i'm looking for a solution in vain, here's my issue:

In my excel file i should generate different sheets with a macro (already done). 
Now on a specified column "L" on all of these generated sheets (starting from sheet number 9), i need an activeX combobox that would contain values brought from un unlimited column(A) of sheet(6).

I started by getting the values by adding values <> "" and storing them in an array.
it's not working, it's all messy, can someone please correct my code and help me, i'd appreciate any help .. thank you in advance

```
Option Explicit

Sub PicklistCopy()
    Dim Nbre As Byte, Arr(), Liste As String, Cptr As Byte
    Dim Current As Worksheet

    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    strSearch = "Pick List Name"

 For Each Current In Worksheets

    Set aCell = Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'copy pl values in an array
    With Sheets("Pick Lists")
         Nbre = Application.CountA(.Range("MyPL"))
         ReDim Arr(1 To .Range("MyPL").Count)
         Arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("MyPL"))
    End With
    'Get values diff from null
    For Cptr = 1 To UBound(Arr)
         If Arr(Cptr) <> "" Then Liste = Liste & Arr(Cptr) & ";"
    Next
    Liste = Left(Liste, Len(Liste) - 1)


    With ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L4").Validation
         .Delete
         .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
         xlBetween, Formula1:=Liste
        .IgnoreBlank = True
         .InCellDropdown = True
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Range("L2:L4") = ""

 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are adding is Data Validation dropdown and not a regular dropdown. Below is my simple code to the the list under the validated cell.

```
Sub AddMyPl()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range
strSearch = "Pick List Name"
 'This will loop thru my sheets in my workbook.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

  'skip the sheet that contains mylist
    If ws.Name <> "mylist" Then
    'get last row # in L column.
LastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
'add validation from MyPL list to cells
    With ws.Range("L2:L" & LastR).Validation
     .Delete
     .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
     xlBetween, Formula1:="=MyPL"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
     .InCellDropdown = True
End With
    End If

    Next ws

End Sub
```

I have 4 sheets. 'mylist' sheet contains MyPL range with the items for my dropdown. The loop will check all sheets which names is not "mylist" then will add the validation dropdown to range L2:L4. 
Modify as needed.

Comment: I tested your suggestion, it's actually creating the combobox on the same sheet (sheet6) from where it gets the values... how can the combobox be affected to all sheets starting from the 9th sheet on the "L" column?

Comment: you will need to loop thru all sheets and add the validation to each. Do a for each sheet in workbooks.. then add the validation.

Comment: Yes I've tried the For Each Current In Worksheets but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please tell me the right syntax to loop and where to put it on my code?

Comment: I edited my response. I don't know I understand what you are trying to do but hope it helps.

Comment: Question, how can i dynamically add these combobox in all filled lines instead of fixing the range to L2:L4? what's the correct syntax to loop through all filled lines in each worksheet?

Comment: Anybody to help meee? i made some modifications and can now add the combobox on the whole line With Range("L:L").Validation. Is there a way to add the combobox only untill the end ot the existing lines?

Comment: Umm..Thanks it displays the combobox but only on the first 2 lines.. I've tried this:
With ws.Range("L:L").Validation
                           .Delete
                           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                            xlBetween, Formula1:=Liste
                            .IgnoreBlank = True
                            .InCellDropdown = True
                          End With
But i don't want the combobox to overpass the grid, i need to put a condition to test that all cells are empty in order to end the loop

Comment: Check the part LastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
'add validation from MyPL list to cells
    With ws.Range("L2:L" & LastR).Validation. Basically LastR will give you the last used row on column L.

Comment: Thanks a lot causita for yout help :)